# Vuejs vuelidate erros : get laravel server errors

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuelidate

In my Laravel 5.5/vue.js2.5 application I used 
vee-validate and vee-validate-laravel ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate-laravel ) libraries.
The last was usefull to work with server errors as with client vuejs errors, and i my code I wrote like :

```
        axios({
            method: ( 'post' ),
        }).then((response) => {
            ...
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.$setLaravelValidationErrorsFromResponse(error.response.data);
            ...
        });
```

Now I use vuelidate ( https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate ) and need some similar decision
I tried to google, but not found, if there is similar library ( or decision ) for server erros in vuelidate?

Thanks !